# Git clone not working for ssh or https but is working for http

Tags: git, github

Does anyone have any clue why this would be happening.

When I go to clone using:

```
      git clone ssh-url
```

it just says `Cloning from 'url'...` but never actually does anything.

I can however clone it with http. But I would like to figure out why this is happening.

EDIT: Also, I am using mysysgit.

UPDATE: I tried reradding my ssh keys to github and then ran ssh -T git@github.com to test if it worked. The following is the resulkting output:

```
 Permissions 0660 for '/home/thebo_000/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
 It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
 This private key will be ignored.
 bad permissions: ignore key: /home/thebo_000/.ssh/id_rsa
 Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Do you have any firewall between you and github?

Comment: I do believe I do. (Believe that is a default Windows settting...and I have not messed with it)

Comment: @nickbonnet we need more information. Do you have SSH keys set up?  Does the remote host have your public key? What happens when you try cloning a public repository, like `git@github.com:git/git.git`?.

Comment: I do have SSH keys setup, The remote host (Github account) does have my public key. What's that easiest way to see if it works on a public repo? Should i actually try to clone that?

Comment: I tried doing this (found it here on SO):
        git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:git/git.git
It does NOT work for SSH (above) but DOES work when using an https url

Comment: I was just trying to avoid cloning something (thought the above thing would be quicker/easier) but I tried cloning now anyways, because it wouldn't matter in the first place if it wasn't working .... which it is not.

Comment: If it works for https but not ssh, sounds like something is wrong there. Are you sure you uploaded your ***public*** key to GitHub? Was it your `id_rsa.pub` file (public) or `id_rsa` file (private).  Also, did you verify that ssh works with `ssh -T git@github.com`, like it says in the instructions in [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)?

Comment: If I do that I get the output that is seen in the UPDATE: section above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ssh key should have the permission 600. Otherwise SSH will not accept your private key out of security precautions. This is the key, where you decrypt the data send from github, which is encrypted with your public key.

You can easily fix this by doing:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This should settle the issue.

On unix the permissons (with ls -l) should look like this:

```
-rw--------
```

Comment: After:
   chmod 600 id_rsa
The permissions look like this:
   -rw-rw----
So how do I get rid of the the other (rw permissions)... sorry I'm new to using the command line for this type of stuff pretty much.

Comment: I had to do: chgrp Users id_rsa and then the cmhod worked correctly. And then doing ssh -T git@github.com worked correctly I believe ... however it seems I am still unable to push to git...

Comment: I forgot that I changed my remote to https:// so once I added a new remote for the ssh:// url then it worked. Your answer was basically correct even though I had to change the group and then do the above (so idk if it'd be the correct thing to do for future onlookers on this questions to mention that). Thank you!